# Unable to mount iPhone unhandled lockdown error

Tags: mount, iphone

I get this error when plugging in my iPhone 3GS.  What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (from imobiledevice.org):

When your device is plugged in, close out the error. Then run

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

Then unplug your device and plug it back in.

Also, if it worked in the first place, but then you reset the iPhone (used Erase all Content and Settings option in the Reset menu in Settings) and it stopped mounting, then the solution is to remove the `~/.config/libimobiledevice/` directory and then replug your iPhone.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Yes, if you upgrade libimobiledevice1 to 1.0.4, and usbmuxd to 1.0.6, it
should solve this error. I can confirm the fix on my system. Since both versions are included in Debian unstable, I'm closing the bug
report. Feel free to reopen it if it's not solve. Regards,
Julien Lavergne From here: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-609012-unhandled-lockdown-error-unable-mount-iphone-help-202616362.html I personally am part way through testing this. Dave

Comment: But I am already using `libimobiledevice 1.1.1` and `usbmuxd 1.0.7`.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that, but I am more interested in what is the cause and what is an "Unhandled Lockdown error", because it was reoccurring problem for me

Comment: This worked for me on 11.04 with iOS 5.0.  However, I needed to run the command `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils` first before I could run `idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair`. (More info [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861617).)

Comment: Can't comment on san's response because I don't have the rep. san's response works; if however after following the unpair/pair instructions and unplugging/plugging your device you still get the error you may need to unlock your device (and, if needed, insert your PIN) and unpair/pair while the device is unlocked. While a device is locked it cannot be paired. wim: In reply to your other comment I believe it may have been because your device was paired with another machine. Unless it's a recurring problem in which case I couldn't say.

Comment: i tried all the advice running updated usbmuxd and libimobile-device-utils
and i am still receiving this error msg. idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair didnt yield a success. Any further recommendations. Thank you. Frank

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me:

**Plug in the iPhone while the computer is either suspended or shut down, or while the Grub startup screen is displayed.**

If you get the popup prompt on the iPhone, tell it to trust the computer, or allow access (however it is worded). If it works for you like it does for me, when the computer starts up the iPhone will be mounted and you will have access lots of data, much more that the folks at Apple would want you to see. Be careful in there.

Edit: I am using an iPhone 6s and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This version of Ubuntu ships with libimobiledevice, which handles the mounting of the iPhone, as I understand it.